# maximum number of selections in an exam

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let 50 students write 7 different exams. A student is said to be *selected* if he/she is in the top 3 in any exam for 4 different times or has topped at least one exam. What is the maximum number of *selections* that is possible? I think the answer is greater than or equal to 15 but am unsure. Any hints. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: In the top 3 for exactly four times or at least four times

Comment: @navinstudent for at least 4 times

Comment: What made you think that the number of selections is greater than or equal to 15 .please consider posting your attempt.

Comment: I think that it might be 10.7 for the toppers in each exam and remaining 14 positions for three students.